# Figma design to react project

Tags: figma, dhiwise

I have figma design. I need to convert React web application. already I have dhiwise & Anima platform. but I want any another tool are available for this purpose of design to code conversion

I am tried Dhiwise platform its working very fine, But I need responsive code for multi viewport. I don't know how to make make responsive in this platform. Anyone help me this problem